Gazebo not lunching ros2 launch gazebo_ros gazebo.launch.py
I am using ubuntu 22.04LTS with ros2-humble  and gazebo-classic I am trying to launch gazebo with following command ros2 launch gazebo_ros gazebo.launch.pynothing happen screen show following output and gazebo does not launch
mubashir@mubashir:~$ ros2 launch gazebo_ros gazebo.launch.py 
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below /home/mubashir/.ros/log/2024-12-04-23-16-42-081194-mubashir-4824
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [gzserver-1]: process started with pid [4825]
[INFO] [gzclient-2]: process started with pid [4827]



I reinstall gazebo and also install from source code but the error is same I also did
sudo apt install ros-humble-gazebo-*

This seems like it starts an empty world correctly. I am guessing your GUI does not open? Can you share the log file mentioned in the first [INFO] line?
